# Can we use 'limit' in update query on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database

I am trying to update my mongodb collection using limit(), But it's not working,is there any other way to apply limit on update query?

Comment: Do it in your filter document

Comment: *"But it's not working"* - in which way does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use limit with update query...It will give

> .update(...).limit is not a function

this error. Because update doesn't return cursor and limit is a cursor function...